# Refresh multiple directive from an angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m actually developping an application with some dashboards with different informations. Actually, I have 6 directives, and each one has his own controller (reusability).

In this application, I manage realtime information transition, and an information received has to refresh each graph, so each directive has to reload.

**Question :**
How can I do without using $scope.$watch or $scope.$observe ?

I dont want to be coupled, so I dont want dependencies between a controller and a directive.

How can I handle that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use events.  One controller broadcasts an event that the others listen for:

Controller ABC:

```
$scope.$broadcast("abcEvent", {});
```

All other controllers:

```
$scope.$on("abcEvent", function (evt, params) {
    // Do something with the event params from abc
});
```